# Namespaces for WCF Web.config, client and server side, maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm not a VB developer and I'm having some issues with Namespace for a Web service. I own both the client and server side of this so I have no issues changing settings.

I'm trying to connect to a webservice and while doing so I get a `MaxReceivedMessageSize` exception. 
They way I go about this is that I have a solution with a "web project" and more "class projects", in one of my "class projects" I have a Service reference and a app.config file where I do my settings.
I have read that I need to have app.config settings in my application and add settings on server web.config for the web service. I'm confused about the namespaces I need to set in the web.config for the web.service on server side. Can anybody help me out a bit? I use this settings

(server)

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Erp_QueryServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="WebService.Erp_QueryService.Erp_QueryServiceSoap">
              <endpoint address="Erp_QueryService.Erp_QueryServiceSoap"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Erp_QueryServiceSoap"
                  contract="Erp_QueryService.Erp_QueryServiceSoap" name="Erp_QueryServiceSoap" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

(client)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Erp_QueryServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="CONNECTION TO SERVICE"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Erp_QueryServiceSoap"
          contract="ServiceQuery.Erp_QueryServiceSoap" name="Erp_QueryServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: hi @Dejan.S i have added an answer not sure though.But i think you are having a problem with that maxItemsInObjectGraph property in web.config file.If my solution is not working please search what you can do with that property and im sure you will find some solution.thanx.

Answer (score 0):

i think may be problem is not with namespaces.
try to set maxItemsInObjectGraph to the following.

**in behaviour section**

```
<behavior name="YourServiceNameBehaviour">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  **<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />**
</behavior>
```

i think you already have added those codes except

```
 **<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />**
```

try adding this code line.